# Two factor authentication using AngularJS, ASP.NET WebAPI and OAuth

Tags: angularjs, authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth, two-factor-authentication

My application uses two factor authentication with username/password followed by a code sent to the user by SMS or e-mail. I've been using cookies to remember users, but now I want to use bearer tokens in OAuth instead, with the help of OWIN.

Does OAuth solve two factor authentication somehow? If not, would it be a bad idea to:

- Client sends (post) user credentials to `/api/authentication` (an ApiController)

  - If credentials are wrong, server responds with `400 Bad Request`
  - If credentials are correct, server generates a code and sends it to the user by SMS. Then it responds with `401 Unauthorize` with `WWW-Authenticate: ???` to the client
- Client sends code to `/token` (OAuth) with `grant_type=password&username={code}`

Comment: I believe this not standard flow supported by OAuth, you are issuing code and sending as its the resource owner.

Comment: Taiseer, I read your ASP.Net OAuth related articles. They are good, for simple username/password authentication scenario. One of our system requires similar two factor authentication. First username & password and then in 2nd step memorable word. Is this possible to achieve with OAuth?